# Read file that contains IPs and write countrycode into new IP.txt file

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I need help with a script that is looking into a file (serverlist.txt) for ip:port.

The serverlist.txt contains rumber numbers of IP:port.

serverlist.txt

```
1.2.3.4:27967
5.6.7.8:27962
6.7.8.9:27968
2.5.6.7:27964
```

The script should cut the port and then request the countrycode with geoiplookup. When its finished, for every ip there should be the countrycode in a new own file like this:

1.2.3.4:27967.txt

```
US
```

5.6.7.8:27962.txt

```
DE
```

This is the code i have till now:

getcountry.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cat serverlist.txt |while read $socket; do cut -f1 -d":">ip.txt; done;
cat ip.txt | while read ip; do geoiplookup $ip | awk -v FS="(GeoIP Country Edition: |,)" '{print $2}'>>countrycode.txt ; done;
```

I can get the ips and the countrycode. But i dont know how to match them together into the new files.
Thanks for any help. ;)

Comment: @fedorqui : Should be the other way right?

Comment: for every ip there should be an own file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's not create an intermediary `ip.txt` file and just loop through the contents in `serverlist.txt`.

By setting the internal field separator (IFS) to `:`, you can extract both `ip` and `port`. Then, run `geoiplookup` against it, pipe to `awk` as you are doing and store the output in a variable `$country`.

Finally, write it into a file named after the ip:

```
while IFS=":" read ip port; do
    country=$(geoiplookup "$ip" | awk -v FS="(GeoIP Country Edition: |,)" '{print $2}')
    printf "$country\n" >> $ip:$port.txt
done < serverlist.txt
```

This is very similar to what you were doing, you only needed to refer to the variable `$ip` to store the name.

```
cat ip.txt | while read ip; do  ... >> $ip.txt ; done;
#                                      ^^^
```

Note I am using the syntax `while read; do ... done < file` instead of `cat file | while ...`, so that you don't open a subshell and all the variables defined within the loop are available outside it.

Comment: Thanks its working. I forgot to write that the new files should be named e.g.: 1.2.3.4:27962.txt. Can you help me with that too?

Comment: @hansfrans sure, you just need to `printf "..." >> $ip:$port.txt` instead. See my update anyway.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Below script

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print $1}' "$1" | while read ip
do
geoiplookup "$ip" | sed 's/GeoIP Country Edition: \([A-Z ]\{2\}\).*/\1/' > "$ip.txt"
done
```

should do it. Execute the script like

```
./script your_file_name
```

If your IP address cannot be resolved, the `ip.txt` file will have the letters `IP` in it meaning that the address couldn't be resolved.

Note that `geoiplookup` can give your either of the two outputs as shown below :

```
me@udistro:~/Documents/so$ geoiplookup 103.233.67.7
GeoIP Country Edition: IP Address not found
```

or

```
me@udistro:~/Documents/so$ geoiplookup 216.239.63.222
GeoIP Country Edition: US, United States
```